# Option to print html input coming from website to wkhtmltopdf

Tags: html, wkhtmltopdf

I am facing a wierd issue in which some pages getting blank due to some UI issue.
Which I am not able to figure out. I checked for un-closed tags or javascripts but couldnot figure out the issue.
So in order to debug the issue I am wondering is there any way to print the input html somewhere which wkhtmltopdf reads to generate pdf.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not through wkhtmltopdf as far as I know, but what is the context in which you are using it exactly? If you're using it from a programming language like Java or C# for example I'd just read the HTTP response from the page and save it as an HTML file and pass that file into wkhtmltopdf.

If you can provide a sample page and some context I could give you a much more specific response.